# ::placeholder::after doesn't work in CSS

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

When I apply `::after` for my `<p>` element, it works fine, but when I use it for the `::placeholder` pseudo-element on my input fields, it doesn't work:

```css
p::after {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
}

#registerFirstName::placeholder::after {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <input id="registerFirstName" tabindex="1" name="registerFirstName" title="" alt="" value="" required="required" maxlength="40" aria-required="true" placeholder="First Name" class="error" aria-invalid="true" type="text">

    <p>I live in Ducksburg</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Can someone help me fixing this?

Comment: `Pseudo-elements` `element` will no work with another `Pseudo-elements` element.

Comment: in that case how i add * next to placeholder? (* should be red color) any other solution do we have then the above one?

Comment: Yes, It have solution.

Comment: 'input' is  a not a container tag that's why it is not work for this type of element. Look '<input />' but <p></p>'.

Comment: first of all...  WHY do you want to do this?  is it just to alert users of an error?  If so, you can do that in other (better) ways, like maybe changing the border color to red on that element.

Comment: @andi It looks to me like it's replacing a field `<label>` by using a placeholder, and the asterisk might be the typical "required" indicator. In any case this is bad UI and absolutely *horrible* for accessibility. They'll definitely end up getting sued under section 508.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code.

First, the pseudo elements can be set *only for elements.* Not for other pseudo elements.

Second, as others already mentioned, generated content pseudo elements (`::before` and `::after`) are not supposed to work on empty elements (those that have no content between start and end tags in the markup) and *usually* they don't (there are some exceptions, but, IIRC, the only browser that allowed these pseudo elements for `<input>` was Opera with Presto engine).

So to add the asterisk in a cross-browser way, you need an extra element. For example, you can do the following:

```css
/* selecting spans immediately following anything with the "placeholder" attribute */
[placeholder] + span::after{
    content:"*";
    color: red;
}
```

```html
        <input id="registerFirstName" tabindex="1" name="registerFirstName" title="" alt="" value="" required="required" maxlength="40" aria-required="true" placeholder="First Name" class="error" aria-invalid="true" type="text">
        <span></span>
```

UPD: Sorry, I missed the part that the asterisk should be next to the placeholder text at first. Unfortunately, it's impossible with CSS. But you can use [the floating label pattern](https://css-tricks.com/float-labels-css/) *instead* of the placeholder, which makes it possible to add the asterisk in the needed place with `::after` pseudo element, and also improves the accessibility of the form in comparison to the bare placeholder solution.

Answer (score 0):

:after and :before are not supported in Internet Explorer 7 and under, on any elements.

It's also not meant to be used on replaced elements such as form elements (inputs) and image elements.

In other words it's impossible with pure CSS.

However if using jquery you can use

```
$(".mystyle").after("add your smiley here");
```

Comment: I need * next to the placeholder firstname (like first name *[red color])can i use above line?

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: I bet they're not supported in Netscape either.  =)

Answer (score 0):

Psuedo elements do not work on empty elements such as `<input>`.

Comment: They _shouldn't,_ but... the reality is a bit more complicated:). For examlpe, the W3C specs themselves style their empty `<hr>` elements with `::after` with three unicode stars, and it works in all browsers ¯ \ _(ツ)_/¯

Comment: True, but they don't work on '<input>', not that I have ever seen anyway!

Comment: According to the old Divya Manian's test (http://jsfiddle.net/nimbu/GvwVy/show/), they work on checkboxes and radio buttons in Chrome:). I don't see much consistency in their behavior, to be honest. Aren't there any plans in the standard bodies to make these things more consistent?